# Laravel: Erro de campo faltando no SQL mesmo passando o campo

Tags: laravel

estou tentando fazer um update no Laravel com:

[image: Código para salvar dados no banco]

A segunda linha desde código só foi adicionada para ter certeza que eu conseguiria passar a data, pois ela já está sendo passada pelo formulário, como pude conferir usando dd($request->all())

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quando envio o código acima ele retorna:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como isto é possível? Sendo que ele passa pelo formulário pode ser conferido pelo dd($request->all()), eu passo manualmente no controler como mostrado na primeira imagem e continua dando este erro, como proceder?

Comment: O campo `dat_documento` está definido no respectivo `Model`?

Comment: Está sim, está como: protected $dates = [
        'dat_documento','dat_resposta'
    ];

Comment: Como foi criada a `migration` desse input? Parece que não foi definido um valor padrão para o `dat_documento` assim como para o `dat_resposta`.

Comment: Mas eu criei para não ser nulo! Está assim $table->date('dat_documento');. A unica diferença dos outros campos da tabela é que tem um ->nullable() na frente

Comment: Tenta colocar no `Model` o seguinte, `protected $fillable = ['dat_documento'];` ou se já houver a variável `fillable`, apenas adicione o `dat_documento` nela.

Comment: Coloquei junto com as outras variáveis no fillable e pegou... Mas eu tou muito curioso da explicação para isto. Eu tenho mais duas model que esta no protected date e funcionou.... Mas obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Talvez as outras `Models` tinham suas `protected $dates` como `->nullable()` nas `migrations`.

Comment: Tem sim, mas elas estão salvando e saindo no relatório e na pagina de alteração. Ou seja, estão salvando. Provavelmente o campo dates só funciona com nullable()...

Answer (score 0):

Como o campo `dat_documento` não foi criado como `nullable`, é necessário adicionar o campo na variável `protected $fillable`.

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal recebi e ajuda e cheguei a seguinte conclusão:
No model estava com ***dat_documento*** e ***dat_resposta*** dentro do *protected $dates*, retirei o campo e coloquei no *fillable* e pegou:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O campo ***dat_documento*** é obrigatório -não aceita nulo - e por algum padrão do Laravel, o protected $dates só funciona quando o campo aceita nulo.
Se aceita nulo ou não deve ser definido na migração.